# Aws Glue Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

Tags: pyodbc, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I want to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using python script which I will execute on AWS Glue. I added JOb parameter at  Security configuration->script libraries->job parameters (optional) section as below :

```
Key : --additional-python-modules
Value: pyodbc==4.0.32,s3://bucketname/python_scripts/python-libs/pyodbc-4.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

When I execute the job I am getting below error :

```
com.amazonaws.services.glue.PythonModuleInstaller   [main]  ERROR: pyodbc-4.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I tried python2 and python3 wheels as well but same error !

Comment: Are you using a Python Shell Glue job or a Spark job?

Comment: its a spark job running python program.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the `--extra-py-files` instead of the `--additional-python-modules` flag for your wheel?

Comment: I tried as below but no luck !
```--extra-py-files s3://bucket/python_scripts/python-libs/pyodbc-4.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl```

```--extra-py-files pyodbc==4.0.32,s3://bucket/python_scripts/python-libs/pyodbc-4.0.32-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl```

still it says module not found!

Answer (score -1):

I raised this with AWS support and figured our that the "pyodbc" package is not compatible with Glue at the moment. Doing a deeper dive into the "pyodbc" package, I found that it requires usage of the C++ language.  Unfortunately, python packages that use other languages are not currently supported by AWS Glue at this time.

Comment: Your answer would greatly benefit from citing a source for your claim that “*python packages that use other languages are not currently supported by AWS Glue at this time.*” so that others can educate themselves on this limitation further.